# Running Swift Playground with Results on Causes Runtime Error

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, runtime-error, swift-playground

I'm currently using an iPad pro on the latest version of Swift Playgrounds. Before compiling I'm given the option to run the program with results or not. When I choose to run with results, my program crashes, but when I choose to run without, it doesn't.

In short, I created a separate swift file called methods where I created a few functions that allow me to create a new view and a new image programmatically. When performance mode is on, my program always crashes on the part where a subview is added (eg. self.addSubview(view)). However, this isn't an issue if the performance mode is off.

I'm not sure if this is a bug or not but any helpful information would be greatly appreciated. Thank you

Here is my methods code (the methods are called in my viewdidload by using `self.view.addView(my parameters)`

```
import UIKit

import PlaygroundSupport

public struct myImages {

    public static var images: [UIImage] = []

}

extension UIView {

    public func addView(x: CGFloat, y: CGFloat, width: CGFloat, height: CGFloat, color: UIColor) {

        var view: UIView!

        view = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: x, y: y, width: width, height: height))

        view.backgroundColor = color
        self.addSubview(view)
    }

    public func addImage(x: CGFloat, y: CGFloat, width: CGFloat, height: CGFloat, img: String) {

        var imageView: UIImageView!

        var image: UIImage!
        image = UIImage(named: img)

        imageView = UIImageView(frame: CGRect(x: x, y: y, width: width, height: height))

        imageView.image = image
        myImages.images.append(image) 
        self.addSubview(imageView)

    }

}
```